# Tutorial : Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

```
import scrapy 

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = "quotes-%s.html" % page
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log("Saved file %s" % filename)
```

Comment: first time when i am using scrapy and after using the official documentation tutorial i am getting this error

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Sidharth Jain. In the future, please don't just post your code alone in the question, but also include some **summary of the issues you are facing and what you have tried to fix it.**

Also in most cases, like this one in particular, including your execution logs would be helpful.

There is nothing wrong with your code, I just executed it and both the files `quotes-1.html` and `quotes-2.html` were created with the expected data.

You probably got a line similar to this in your execution:

```
2020-10-02 18:28:32 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

This is merely an informative log, it's shown when the spider is started and if the spider runs for a longer time you will see it beign updated by the minute. Since in this case the spider finishes in less than a second, you wont see any updates.

More importantly in this case is to make sure you have the lines: (Assuming your `LOG_LEVEL` is `DEBUG`)

```
2020-10-02 18:28:33 [quotes] DEBUG: Saved file quotes-1.html
2020-10-02 18:28:33 [quotes] DEBUG: Saved file quotes-2.html
```

If you don't, than the next step would be to make sure you are running the right spider. If this still doesn't helps, please include your execution logs in the question.